# AndroidX dependencies and XML causing crash

Tags: android, xml, layout, dependencies, androidx

I recently updated to Android 3.3, Now a lot of dependencies are changed to `AndroidX`. Which is causing the app to crash, along with dependency changes need to be done in `XML` as well. I faced a similar issue with `CoordinatorLayout`. I searched stackoverflow there aren't a lot of Questions on this topic, since `AndroidX` is relatively new. So i felt the need to raise a question in this regard.

Where can i get xml for `FloatingActionButton` similarly for all the `XML` is there a website where we can get the XML for androidX dependencies.

**XML**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

**Crash Logcat**

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML
> file line #15: Error inflating class
> android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton" on path:
> DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/com.kc.unsplashdemo-kTZQS-p2845Xly7PcTuAmg==/base.apk", zip
> file
> "/data/app/com.kc.unsplashdemo-kTZQS-p2845Xly7PcTuAmg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
> zip file

**dependencies**

```
dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation project(':androidunsplash')
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
        implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0")
        implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.1'
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked this doc https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate ?

Comment: yes, that only covers Dependencies, not XML.

Comment: Yeah, basically you have to change all your old appcompat components to androidx components. When you migrate to androidx

Comment: I understand I changed dependencies in gradle, but the app is crashing. I need a link or any documentation of all androidX XML. Or any automatic way to convert all XML to androidX. I used android studio's tools > migrate to AndrodiX. That doesn't seem to work for XML

Comment: For example from androidx, floating action button. Migrated from `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` to `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton`. Or you can also refract your whole project through navigation menu.

Comment: Android X dependency already added. I updated my question and posted dependencies as well.

Comment: Have you enabled `jetifier` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the mapping for the old android **dependencies** against the **new ones** who use **androidx** [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

There you'll find this for the dependency you're looking for:

```
com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
```

When replacing something on a layout I'd suggest using `ctrl + r` to update it in the whole project and save you time, as there's indeed quite a bit of manual work to do when migrating to androidx.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a dependency for androidX is not enough. To migrate your components to the androidX one, you have to change them manually. While searching for all the new packages may be time consuming, I can suggest you to try deleting old name in your xml and then start typing a new one. If androidX dependencies are really added to your project, after you started typing Android Studio will suggest you a new package name.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Furthermore, you can look for additional information [here](https://blog.danlew.net/2018/11/14/the-reality-of-migrating-to-androidx/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are facing issue when you upgraded the Android Studio to 3.3. To fix this following things can be done:
a) If you have migrated your code to Androidx check the `gradle.properties` in the app if these two lines are not there:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

then go to `Refactor -> Migrate to Androidx` in android studio that migrates your app to Androidx including xml files. This option will show changes in the terminal below accept those changes to migrate to Androidx.

b) If doing this doesn't work and you still get that error replace this

> android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

with

> com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

which is taken from the mapping file provided by google which maps earlier support library classes to the androidx package classes :
[Migrating to Androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)